I am not able to move the paddle
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("White")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("Pong")

paddle = Turtle()
paddle.shape("square")
paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle.penup()
paddle.goto(x=380, y = 0)



def go_up():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() + 20
    paddle.goto = (paddle.xcor(), new_y)

def go_down():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() - 20
    paddle.goto = (paddle.xcor(), new_y)

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(go_up, ('Up'))
screen.onkeypress(go_down, ('Down'))




screen.exitonclick()

The above code was written to move the paddle up and down on pressing up and down button respectively in Windows PC. However, the paddle is not moving up and down when I am pressing the up and down keys. Can you please help?

Err, don't you need a screen.mainloop() to start the event pump?

@paxdiablo Some online IDEs like trinket (I think) add that for you. Not a bad idea though in general.

In turtle, everything is a method call, both getters and setters. You basically never use = to work with the turtle API, only your own variables.

paddle.goto is a function
instead of calling the function, you appear to be assigning to it.
so this:
def go_up():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() + 20
    paddle.goto = (paddle.xcor(), new_y)

def go_down():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() - 20
    paddle.goto = (paddle.xcor(), new_y)

should actually be:
def go_up():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() + 20
    paddle.goto(paddle.xcor(), new_y)

def go_down():
    new_y = paddle.ycor() - 20
    paddle.goto(paddle.xcor(), new_y)

This appears to work for me
